# Axios and nodejs: 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, axios

I'm trying to post some data into my db. In particular, I take the data entered in a form and I send a request to my backend (nodejs) at the address http://localhost:4000/insert. Anyway, when I tried to do that, I received many errors, so I modified the url in "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:4000/insert". But now, I receive this error:
VM161:1 POST https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:4000/insert 403 (Forbidden).

This app is very simple, so I'm not using any type of authentication; and I'm not requiring any type of authentication. How can I solve this problem? Here is my code: Thank you so much for your help!

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function Insert(){

    const url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:4000/insert"
    const[data, setData] = useState({

        description: "",
        distance: "",
        hours: "",
        minutes: "",
        seconds: "",


    })

    function submit(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post(url,{
            description : data.description,
            distance: data.distance,
            hours: data.hours,
            minutes : data.minutes,
            seconds : data.seconds

        })
            .then(res =>{
                console.log(res.data)
            })

    }


    function handle(e){

        const newdata={...data}
        newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.value
        setData(newdata)
        console.log(newdata)

    }

    return(

        <div>
            <form onSubmit={(e)=> submit(e)}>
                <p>Insert the details of your run</p>
                <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id="description" value={data.description} type="text"></input>
                <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id="distance" value={data.distance} type="text"></input>
                <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id="hours" value={data.hours} type="text"></input>
                <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id="minutes" value={data.minutes} type="text"></input>
                <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id="seconds" value={data.seconds} type="text" ></input>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    );



}

export default Insert;
```

**Here is my backend code: index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const routesHandler = require('./routes/handler.js')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use('/', routesHandler);
app.use(cors())





const PORT = 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    
    console.log('Server is running on port ' + PORT + '.')

});
```

**handler.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql')



var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'appdb',
    multipleStatements: true
  })
  
  
  
  
  conn.connect((err) =>{
    if(!err)
    console.log("Connection to DB succeded.")
    if(err)
    console.log("Can't connect to DB." + err)
  })
  

router.get('/tweets', (req,res) =>{

    const str =[{

        "name" : "Raffaele",
        "msg" : "Forza Italia!",
        "username" : "rdp"

    }];
    res.end(JSON.stringify(str));
});

router.post('/addtweet', (req,res) =>{

    res.end('NA');

});


router.get('/read',(req,res) => {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM run', (err,rows,fields) =>{
        if(!err)
        res.send(rows)
        else
        console.log(err)
    })
})


router.post('/insert',(req,res) =>{


    jsondata = req.body;
    description = jsondata['description'];
    distance = jsondata['distance'];
    hours = jsondata['hours'];
    minutes = jsondata['minutes'];
    seconds = jsondata['seconds'];


    conn.query('INSERT INTO run (description, distance, hours, minutes, seconds) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [description,distance,hours,minutes,seconds], (err) =>{
        if(err)
        res.send(err)
        if(!err)
        res.send("Insert succeded.")
        
    })
})



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of those long URLs and complexity of managing cors, you can use this **popular npm package** named **"cors"** to better manage your CORS-related problems.

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
 
app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: If I remove the heroku link (also adding the settings you said) I receive the following error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/insert' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: sure. I added the backend code in editing my question. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: try placing app.use(cors()) before routes.

Answer (score 0):

However this is not an issue but please check this line of code

```
const url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:4000/insert"
```

the url seemed a bit awkward to me

also you should add

```
headers: {
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've consulted many tutorials. The original url was http://localhost:4000/insert. Anyway if I send a post request to this url, I receive many cors error. In this tutorials, many people said to add https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ immediatly before the original url. Is this correct in your opinion? I'm not expert in general about nodejs and axios

Comment: is your frontend running on localhost:3000 port?

Comment: yes, it is. the frontend is running on the 3000 and the backend is running on the 4000.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure everything is ok on your server first.

- use `app.use(cors())` at top of all middleware functions.
- Check your backend is connected to your DB.
- then try to post data to your local server URL "http://localhost:4000/insert" only.

Comment: The backend works properly. I've tested all the functionalities with postman.

Comment: You need to use the app.use(cors()); before your routing functions get called. Write this  app.use(cors()); after this line of code const app = express();